# How to do long list of parameters in jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a long list of parameters I have to pass into a jQuery `.removeClass` function.

How do I add them all into one parenthesis separated by commas? Currently it looks like this...

```
     $("#bottom-nfl").click(function(){
        $("#bottom-mlb i, #bottom-mlb small").removeClass("orange");
        $("#bottom-nba i, #bottom-nba small").removeClass("orange");
        $("#bottom-ncaab i, #bottom-ncaab small").removeClass("orange");
        $("#bottom-profile i, #bottom-profile small").removeClass("orange");
    });
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
     $("#bottom-nfl").click(function(){
        $("#bottom-mlb i, #bottom-mlb small,
        #bottom-nba i, #bottom-nba small,
        #bottom-ncaab i, #bottom-ncaab small
        #bottom-profile i, #bottom-profile small").removeClass("orange");
    });
```

But that  resultes in `unterminated string literal` error.

I tried with the backslash to escape the newlines but that doesn't work either

Comment: Did you test it? This should work.

Comment: $("#bottom-nfl").click(function() {
  $("#bottom-mlb i, #bottom-mlb small, #bottom-nba i, #bottom-nba small, #bottom-ncaab i, #bottom-ncaab small,#bottom-profile i, #bottom-profile small").removeClass("orange");
});

Comment: @prettyInPink I did try but I get unterminated string lateral. I tried with the backslash to escape it but that doesn't work either.

Comment: You cannot split the string like that. Use template literals

Comment: For a multiline string you need to use backticks or concatenate each line with a `+`

Comment: @RyanThomas Please see update. I made a shorter version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) here if you want to split the string and that allows you to format the list

Also you missed a comma

```
 $("#bottom-nfl").on("click", function(){
    $(`#bottom-mlb     i, #bottom-mlb     small,
       #bottom-nba     i, #bottom-nba     small,
       #bottom-ncaab   i, #bottom-ncaab   small,
       #bottom-profile i, #bottom-profile small`).removeClass("orange");
});
```

or program it

```
$("#bottom-nfl").on("click", function(){
  ["mlb","nba","ncaab","ncaab","profile"]
    .forEach(cls => $(`#bottom-${cls} i, #bottom-${cls} small`).removeClass("orange"));
});
```

Actually escaping the newline SHOULD work, but the template literals are prettier

```
 $("#bottom-nfl").on("click", function(){
    $("#bottom-mlb     i, #bottom-mlb     small,\
       #bottom-nba     i, #bottom-nba     small,\
       #bottom-ncaab   i, #bottom-ncaab   small,\
       #bottom-profile i, #bottom-profile small").removeClass("orange");
});
```